# How can I write a Perl one-liner for a Makefile so I can translate a literal \n to a newline?

Tags: regex, perl

I need to escape \n so on output I really get newline or tab

```
$ perl -p -e 's/e/a/ge'
```

now I want each e to be substituted with \n

```
$ perl -p -e 's/e/\n/ge'
```

but even \n gives me an error.

this was a simplified example. In real script(makefile) I have

```
substitute := perl -p -e 's/@([^@]+)@/defined $$ENV{$$1} ? $$ENV{$$1} : $$1/ge'
```

and in target I have such a nice command

```
$(substitute) $< > $@
```

and if the input file for perl contains `\n` at output I will see it literally... I want to have real newline.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `e` modifier and the substitution will work fine:

```
perl -p -e 's/e/\n/g' file
```

From [perldoc perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html):

```
e   Evaluate the right side as an expression.
```

UPD: If you want to preserve it, put the escape sequence in double quotes:

```
perl -p -e 's/e/"\n"/ge' file
```

Comment: guess I need it, because of this in real case `perl -p -e 's/@([^@]+)@/defined $$ENV{$$1} ? $$ENV{$$1} : $$1/ge'`. And this thing goes to makefile... the real world is too complicated ^^

Comment: @Michael -- where's the `\n` or `\t` in there?

Comment: @Joe: I've updated my original post. Sorry guys I thought things are simple... looks not.

Comment: @eugene y: didn't work, can see "\n" in output. The string from the variable passed to replacement part is like this `em:updateURL="http://bla/update.rdf""\n"` (the last one per your recommendation.

Comment: @Michael: you need an extra e along with the quotes; see my answer

Comment: @ysth: extra `e` didn't help, sorry

Comment: @Michael: what *did* happen?  Can you show a snipped down makefile and tell us what the output of make -n should be?

Answer (score 3):

You don't really need `e` in your regexp:

```
dpavlin@llin:~/private/home_html$ perl -p -e 's/e/\n/g'
foedoe
fo
do
```

Answer (score 3):

To interpolate things that themselves need interpolation (like variables or escapes), use a double e and add quotes:

```
perl -p -e 's/@([^@]+)@/q!"! . ( defined $ENV{$1} ? $ENV{$1} : $1 ) . q!"!/gee'
```

That won't work if the substitution itself contains an unescaped " or $ or @; in that case, you'll need to do the backslash-escape handling separately.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo xeieio | perl -pe 's/(.)/$k=$1;$k=~s#e#\n#;$k/ge'
```

outputs:

> x
>   i
>   io

What it does... for each character, assign it to $k, run a simple s/e/\n/ on $k, then print $k.  (Also, as always, there's more than one way to do it)